# How do I fix the 'drivers is undefined' error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, undefined

This function is currently set to grab both feeds and store the results in a global variable, then it calls the compare function and loops through the weekend feed to create an array of objects. Currently, I keep getting an error saying 'drivers is undefined' and was wondering if anyone can help me fix it?

```
            var weekendFeed = {};
            var driversFeed = {};
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery.getJSON("https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2021/1/5044/weekend-feed.json")
                    .done(function(res){
                        weekendFeed = res;
                        jQuery.getJSON("https://www.nascar.com/json/drivers/")
                            .done(function(res){
                                driversFeed = res;
                                compareFeeds();
                            });
                    });
                function compareFeeds(){
                    //console.log(weekendFeed.weekend_race[0].results);
                    //console.log(driversFeed);
                    var weekendDrivers = [];
                    for(driver in weekendFeed.weekend_race[0].results){
                        drivers.push({"id" : weekendFeed.weekend_race[0].results[driver].driver_id});
                        drivers.push({"name" : weekendFeed.weekend_race[0].results[driver].driver_fullname});
                        drivers.push({"make" : weekendFeed.weekend_race[0].results[driver].car_make});
                    }
                    console.log(weekendDrivers);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Inside compare function's for loop, there is a `drivers` variable being used as array. Can you point to where is it defined? Or is it a mistake for `weekendDrivers`?

Comment: @DipanshuKumarSuman thank you for your help! I replaced drivers.push with the weekendDrivers and I received the original array I wanted